# Where can I find a decent, representative sample dataset in json for test purposes?

Tags: json, testing

I'm looking for a set of data that contains both numbers and strings (name/address, maybe), with a decent variety of data, around 1000 records, to test a JQuery-UI widget I'm developing. Does anyone know of such a dataset? Is there something floating around out there I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ... http://www.generatedata.com/#generator ... amazing tool to create whatever dataset you'd like

Comment: @ChrisMcCall - the generator does now have a JSON option.

Comment: and this tool is opensource (php,mysql), so you could download it and customize it too!